# How do I add a launcher to a panel during rpm install in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: linux, packaging, gnome, rpm, rpm-spec

Does anyone know how to put a launcher in the panel for an application during an rpm install? For example next to the firefox launcher.

I'm guessing it might involve moving the .desktop file into a directory during %post in the spec file?

The rpm is for a RHEL 6.1 system with gnome.

I'm creating an rpm from a spec file for a project I'm working on. I've also put a launcher into the Applications\Accessories menu using the .desktop file. I've been asked to put a launcher into the panel for the application and have tried searching with little success.

Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNOME 2 to manually add a launcher to the top panel, you need to put the same `.desktop` file, you used for Desktop Launcher, to `$home/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers/`. Where `$home` should be resolved to the user's home path.

**UPDATE**

In addition to putting the launcher there you need to register it.

Just run `/usr/lib/gnome-panel/gnome-panel-add --panel=top_panel_screen0 --launcher=<full path to your launcher>`. You can also add `--copy-launcher` switch to make the tool copy the launcher to the user's `launchers` directory for you.

Comment: I've put the same .desktop file into the directory /home/user/.../launchers/ as suggested (for a user called user). I also logged in/out and the launcher hasn't appeared. It might be worth mentioning that there's no other files in that directory.

Comment: I've managed to get it working :D, although gnome-panel-add's location was a little different on my system /usr/libexec/gnome-panel-add I also just loaded the launcher from /usr/applications/launcherName.desktop